# Returning Only First Distinct Value In Sorted MySql Join Query

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have two MySql tables, once for "Locations" and one for "Images". I need to get a list of the most recent Image taken at a particular **set** of Locations (which is a comma-delimited list), but I only want to return the record for the most recent Image and I've been struggling mightily with getting the right results so far.

So, I have:

```
Locations:
+---------------------------------------------+
| ID | Name                                   |
|----|----------------------------------------|
|  1 | Indiana                                |
|  2 | Ohio                                   |
|  3 | Illinois                               |
+---------------------------------------------+

Images:
+---------------------------------------------+
| ID | User  | Location  |  Date              |
|----|-------|-----------|--------------------|
|  1 | Ray   | 1         | 2012-06-22         |
|  2 | Robert| 3         | 2011-09-18         |
|  3 | Marie | 1         | 2012-10-01         |
|  4 | Frank | 2         | 2010-12-11         |
|  5 | Debra | 1         | 2008-02-02         |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

So, right now I have the following:

```
SELECT Locations.Name, Images.Date, Images.User
FROM Locations INNER JOIN Images ON Locations.ID = Images.Location
WHERE Locations.ID IN ('1','3')
ORDER BY Images.Date DESC
```

Which returns:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| Name        | Date        |  User           |
|-------------|-------------|-----------------|
| Indiana     | 2012-10-01  | Marie           |
| Indiana     | 2012-06-22  | Ray             |
| Illinois    | 2011-09-18  | Robert          |
| Indiana     | 2008-02-02  | Debra           |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

My question is, how can I get it so that the result returns only the first record with a distinct Location.Name value? So the final, correct result table would look like:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| Name        | Date        |  User           |
|-------------|-------------|-----------------|
| Indiana     | 2012-10-01  | Marie           |
| Illinois    | 2011-09-18  | Robert          |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Very well explained requirement

Comment: @Sashi Kant: Thanks! I definitely worked hard to make sure the example was as clear as possible.

Comment: Have updated my query, please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SImply uSe `group by`::

```
Select tempTable.Name, tempTable.Date, tempTable.User from
(
    SELECT Locations.Name, Images.Date, Images.User, Locations.ID as locationID
    FROM Locations 
    INNER JOIN Images ON Locations.ID = Images.Location
    WHERE Locations.ID IN ('1','3')

    ORDER BY Images.Date DESC

) as tempTable GROUP BY  tempTable.locationID
```

Comment: This does not return the most recent Image record first. Since it does the grouping before the ordering, it ends up returning only two records, but they are two random records rather than the most recent.

Comment: Perfect! I did add an additional `ORDER BY Date DESC` at the very end just to get that final table of two records to be sorted on the `Date` column as well, but that's not a big deal. This was the exact answer I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Uncanny. This is exactly what I needed too! Thanks!